# Why I obtain this error message when I try to execute this insert query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have some problem with a method that execute an **insert** query into a table on a Microsof SQL Server DB.

So I have this method:

```
public bool insertVulnerabilityAlertDocument_Cpe(long currentNVDVulnId, long cpeId)
{

        System.Data.Common.DbCommand command;
        command = _connection.CreateCommand();

        //long newId = -1;

        _strSQL = "INSERT INTO VulnerabilityAlertDocument_Cpe ([VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId] , [CpeId], [DateAdded] ) VALUES ( @VULNERABILITYALERTDOCUMENTID , @CPEID, GETDATE() )";
        addParameter(command, " @VULNERABILITYALERTDOCUMENTID ", int.Parse(currentNVDVulnId.ToString()));
        addParameter(command, " @CPEID ", int.Parse(cpeId.ToString()));
        command.CommandText = _strSQL;

        _executeNoQuery(command);

        return true;

 }
```

The problem is that when try to execute this query I obtain the following exception:

> - ex  {"ExecuteNonQuery terminato con errori. \r\nINSERT INTO VulnerabilityAlertDocument_Cpe ([VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId] ,
>     [CpeId], [DateAdded] ) VALUES ( @VULNERABILITYALERTDOCUMENTID ,
>     @CPEID, GETDATE() )\r\nIncorrect syntax near
>     '@VULNERABILITYALERTDOCUMENTID'.\r\nMust declare the scalar variable
>     \"@VULNERABILITYALERTDOCUMENTID\"."}  System.Exception
>     {MyManagerCSharp.MyException}

What could be the exact problem? And what can I do to solve it?

Tnx

Comment: Try removing the leading and trailing spaces in your parameter names. For example, `"@VULNERABILITYALERTDOCUMENTID"` instead of `" @VULNERABILITYALERTDOCUMENTID "`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove extra spaces in `" VULNERABILITYALERTDOCUMENTID "` and `" @CPEID "`.